# Determining a good threshold to separate Seurat Object by a specific gene's expression

Tags: r, seurat

I am trying to annotate cells in my Seurat Object as either positive or negative for a particular gene. I was wondering whether there was any particular way of determining a good threshold of saying when a cell is positive or negative in expressing a particular gene?

This was a sample code that annotated Lyz positive cells from Github.

```
lyz.pos <- WhichCells(object = pbmc_small, expression = LYZ > 1)
```

I was also wondering what the expression level> 1 means? Is it log-transformed or is it raw mRNA counts? Given that, how should we approach setting a good threshold for whether a cell is positive or negative for a particular gene?